# jQuery load function with fading effects not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I have the following scenario

```
jQuery('#content').fadeOut('slow',function(){
    jQuery('#content').load("detail.php?product="+imgID+"&category="+cat);
    jQuery('#content').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

My problem however is that all the effects happen and when the effects are done, then only the contents of the PHP file loads into content, is there a better way so that the content is not slow in loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the callback function of the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. Like so:

```
jQuery("#content").load("detail.php?product="+imgID+"&category="+cat, function()
{
    jQuery("#content").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

This way; your animation won't start until the content has been loaded.